# Android SDK 30 paths issue

Tags: android, path, filepath, scoped-storage

Me and my team are going to start to compile with Android SDK30, until now we used SDK29 with flag requestLegacyExternalStorage set to true.
To be clear my application is using the below paths:

1. /storage/emulated/0/MyCustomFolder
2. /storage/emulated/0/Android

About the first one: "/storage/emulated/0/MyCustomFolder". We would like to retrieve all data in MyCustomFolder
About the second one: "/storage/emulated/0/Android". We would like to retrieve some specific files in it
So my questions are:

1. Is it possible compiling with Android SDK30 and at least add the
   read access to above paths to copy files?
2. Are there any path or APIs that will permit to store persistent data
   also after app uninstall process?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

regarding [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage) you have only one option - introducing [`MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access) permission, then using some custom folder for keeping files to "survive" re-install operation. note that Google Play Store probably won't accept your app if it isn't storage-manager-kind-app

without this permission when you update your app with target = API30 you will lose access to both listed paths and there is no workaround for that (besides above perm), thats the purpose of Scoped Storage feature introduction in Android OS: limiting uncontrolled storage access for security purposes

Comment: Surely in next app version I'll remove the flag from manifest, also because it will be discarded from what I read into the documentation. So there are no way to retrieve my old data?

Comment: when you start targeting 30+ and without mentioned permission you won't get access to these directories. thats why Scoped Storage was introduced with this opt-out flag working in one "transitional" OS version for a year (regarding Google Play policy: even two) - that gave you a time to update your app with still old target and additional code, which moves these files from some "public" directories to app-specific. afaik sooner or later (end of this summer?) Google Play won't accept such old-target app updates